# VueJS JS-only transition hook requires setTimeout for CSS transition to work

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions, transition

I'm working with pure JS hooks for the `<transition-group>` element on VueJS, and I am quite puzzled on how the `enter` hook actually works. Based on the documentation, I understand that I will have to [call `done()` to avoid events being called synchronously](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html?#JavaScript-Hooks):

> When using JavaScript-only transitions, the `done` callbacks are required for the `enter` and `leave` hooks. Otherwise, the hooks will be called synchronously and the transition will finish immediately.

However, even when I use it, it seems to stop CSS transitions from happening in the **entering transition**. The only solution I found is to use `window.setTimeout` to set the style, which I think is a code smell. Here is a quick visual comparison between the code without the timeout, and the one with (the one with the timeout is the desired effect):

Broken enter transition (no transition of the left padding and opacity):

[image: Broken enter transition]

Desired enter transition:

[image: Desired effect]

In the example below, I am displaying a list using `<transition-group>` and wanted to use JS-hooks so that I can create staggered paddings on individual list items. It seems to work with the exception that in the `enter` transition, the CSS transitions on the padding property does not work.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      'Lorem',
      'Ipsum',
      'Dolor',
      'Sit',
      'Amet'
    ],
    toggle: false
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
      if (!this.toggle)
        return [];

      return this.items;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItems: function() {
      this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    },
    beforeEnter: function(el) {
      el.style.paddingLeft = '0px';
      el.style.opacity = '0';
    },
    enter: function(el, done) {
      el.style.paddingLeft = `${10 * +el.dataset.index}px`;
      el.style.opacity = '1';
      done();
    },
    beforeLeave: function(el) {
      el.style.paddingLeft = '0px';
      el.style.opacity = '0';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button @click="toggleItems">
    Toggle items
  </button>
  
  <transition-group
    tag="ul"
    @before-enter="beforeEnter"
    @enter="enter"
    @before-leave="beforeLeave">
    
    <li
      v-for="(item, i) in filteredItems"
      v-bind:key="i"
      v-bind:data-index="i">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

If you wrap all the logic inside the `enter` method inside an arbitrary timout, then it works:

```
enter: function(el, done) {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    el.style.paddingLeft = `${10 * +el.dataset.index}px`;
    el.style.opacity = '1';
    done();
  }, 100);
},
```

And this is where I am a little confused: does the `enter` hook not wait for `beforeEnter` to complete first? The working snippet is as follow

Comment: You shouldn't call `done` in the `enter` method. `done` call back only require in JavaScript-only transitions. You are using mixed CSS transition and javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `@enter` hook to `@after-enter` should fix it

I have no clue why the `@enter` hook isn't working for this, as looking at the documentation it *should* but this should at least get rid of the timeout without being a hack

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      'Lorem',
      'Ipsum',
      'Dolor',
      'Sit',
      'Amet'
    ],
    toggle: false
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
      if (!this.toggle)
        return [];

      return this.items;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItems: function() {
      this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    },
    beforeEnter: function(el) {
      el.style.paddingLeft = '0px';
      el.style.opacity = '0';
    },
    afterEnter: function(el) {
      el.style.paddingLeft = `${10 * +el.dataset.index}px`;
      el.style.opacity = '1';
    },
    beforeLeave: function(el) {
      el.style.paddingLeft = '0px';
      el.style.opacity = '0';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

li.v-enter-active {
  transition: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button @click="toggleItems">
    Toggle items
  </button>

  <transition-group 
    tag="ul" 
    @before-enter="beforeEnter"
    @after-enter="afterEnter" 
    @before-leave="beforeLeave">
    <li v-for="(item, i) in filteredItems" v-bind:key="i" v-bind:data-index="i">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

As a side note, if you're using SCSS or SASS, you can achieve this with that rather than JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) even though this doesvisually  fix the problem, you'll notice that there is some delay before the list items actually transition in. I suspect that the `after-enter` hook is called a bit too late.

Comment: @Terry Hi, I've just edited the answer now, it was because the transition was running/executing for the `@before-enter` and the `@after-enter` so it was taking 1s half of that being invisible, adding a new ccs ruling fixes this.